# Write map to file using for_each

Tags: c++, stdmap

The following code compiles and executes, but nothing is written to the file and I cannot for the life of me figure out why. The file is being created, but the file is empty. I made sure to delete the file each time just in case but that shouldn't make a difference

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <iterator>
#include <map>
#include <set>
using namespace std;

int main(){

    set<string> exclusionSet;
    ifstream stopWords("stopwords.txt");
    copy(istream_iterator<string>(stopWords),
            istream_iterator<string>(),
            inserter(exclusionSet, exclusionSet.end()));

    stopWords.close();

    //for_each(exclusionSet.begin(),
//          exclusionSet.end(),
//          [](const string& s){cout<<s<<endl;});

    map<string, int> wordMap;
    ifstream words("sample_doc.txt");
    copy_if(istream_iterator<string>(words),
            istream_iterator<string>(),
            inserter(exclusionSet, exclusionSet.end()),
            [=](const string& s){return exclusionSet.find(s)!=exclusionSet.end();});

    ofstream out("frequency.txt");

    for_each(begin(wordMap),
            end(wordMap),
            [&out](const pair<const string, int>& e){ out<<e.first<<" "<<e.second<<endl;});
    out.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You never insert anything into `wordMap`.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the following version of the fixes

```
int main()
{
    map<string, int> wordMap;

    set<string> exclusionSet;
    ifstream stopWords("stopwords.txt");
    copy(istream_iterator<string>(stopWords), istream_iterator<string>(), inserter(exclusionSet, exclusionSet.end()));
    stopWords.close();

    vector<string> strings;    
    ifstream words("sample_doc.txt");
    copy_if(istream_iterator<string>(words), istream_iterator<string>(), inserter(strings, strings.end()),
        [=](const string& s)
        {
            return exclusionSet.find(s) == exclusionSet.end();
        });
    words.close();

    for(auto &a : strings)
        wordMap[a] = wordMap[a] + 1;

    ofstream out("frequency.txt");

    for_each(begin(wordMap), end(wordMap),
        [&out](const pair<const string, int>& e)
        {
            out << e.first << " " << e.second << endl;
        });

    out.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Main differences:

1. reading the data from the file "sample_doc" in the vector *strings*, checking whether they are in exclusionSet (fix yours **find_if** call)
2. forming words frequency statistics with:

   ```
   for(auto &a : strings)
       wordMap[a] = wordMap[a] + 1;
   ```

And.... I'd rather replace **for_each** to range-based **for**, like this:

```
for(const auto &e: wordMap)
    out << e.first << " " << e.second << endl;
```

Comment: Very nice thanks! Unfortunately for the purpose of this assignment I cant use a range based for, only stl container functions.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have much to add on top of @snake_style's answer, but I would like to point out that you can easily drop the complexity/expense of using `copy_if` to filter the words in `sample_doc.txt` by using a simple `while` loop:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <iterator>
#include <map>
#include <set>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    set<string> exclusionSet;
    ifstream stopWords("stopwords.txt");
    copy(istream_iterator<string>(stopWords),
            istream_iterator<string>(),
            inserter(exclusionSet, exclusionSet.end()));

    stopWords.close();

    map<string, int> wordMap;
    ifstream words("sample_doc.txt");
    string s;

    while(words >> s) if (exclusionSet.count(s)==0) ++wordMap[s];

    ofstream out("frequency.txt");

    for_each(begin(wordMap),
            end(wordMap),
            [&out](const pair<const string, int>& e){ out<<e.first<<" "<<e.second<<endl;});
    out.close();
    return 0;
}
```